# Is it possible to bypass ApplicationPool Identity and use back user's domain account to connect SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, iis, dns

There is an web app that has been well setup to use an Application Pool Identity to connect to the SQL Server.

And then my app somehow it requires to use the user's own domain account and login as a SSPI type authentication.

Is it possible to revert back such silly way at all?

Comment: The first sentence sounds like the correct setup. I have no clue what you're trying to say in the second sentence - can you clarify that?

Comment: My web app requires to user's own domain account which actually applied the appropriate access right for DB access. The legacy appPool Identity contains all access right for the whole DB which is too risky to use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  That's called Impersonation, and it's documented here: [ASP.NET Impersonation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/development/implement-impersonation)

This requires particular HTTP Auth schemes, and some domain setup.  As an alternative you can use SQL Server-level impersonation with the [EXECUTE AS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)/[REVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/revert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thanks David! After certrain attempts I think the EXECUTE AS approach is what I need. But there's another issue that's still causing problem: the VB.net application's User.Identity.name class is stating the AppPool's user instead the real domain user behind. Is it even possible to revert this back?

Answer (score 0):

There's two options really; the one it sounds like you're thinking of is indeed Impersonation, as David says in his answer.

The other option (which requires less maintenance on the database side), is to use the setup referred to in the first sentence of your question and (assuming this is an intranet system and you're using an Active Directory to manage your users in the domain) assign your users the relavent roles within the Active Directory. Then you can simply use the `Page.User.IsInRole("MyRole")` method to manage what users can actually access within the webapp.

Personally, I lean more towards the second option as it means you're only giving a limited handful of people (the devs) direct access to the database.